# PHP Class OOP Based Apache Mod Rewrite System (Permalinks - Friendly URL's)

Tags: php, mysql, apache, mod-rewrite, seo

Now I have been scouring the web for what seems to be a mystery or maybe I am searching for the wrong things, but does anyone know of any good Object Oriented ways on managing "Pretty URLs' in PHP using Apache Mod Rewrite that can run dynamically i.e a database such as MySQL?

I have been trialing some methods with my current but "limited" know-how of PHP. I understand that with this .htaccess file you can request all URLS to one file whilst accessing other folders as long as they exist:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Thats all fine and dandy. I also know that you can explode the server path like so:

```
$path = explode('/', $_SERVER['PATH_INFO']);
```

I am looking for something similar in terms of functionality how WordPress handles it's permalink system, you are able to create pretty much any URL and the system will know how to handle the request and also how to display + write the URLS when requested for redirects or on page.

Is this asking to much? Or do I need to re-invent the wheel as such? This has been bugging me for a long time that I cannot find a scalable solution that can I can use 'out of the box' and customize to my needs - maybe there is and you can enlighten me? ;)

I was thinking you could somehow define rules via:

```
$rewrite_object->addRule(array(
    'Page' => array(
        'label' =>  'Page',
        'rewrite' => '/'
    )
));
```

This would be controlled by a class instance from the example of above but hopefully you can see what I am trying to put across.

I hope I have explained this as much as possible! To clarify - I NEED a solution for creating a structured, easy to maintain, highly extendable way of creating SEO friendly URLs for a variety of content, whether it be: articles, pages, categories or whatever you can think of.

I look forward to your thoughts!

Comment: Part of what you're describing sounds like a Router, commonly used in frameworks. [Zend Framework](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.router.html) - [CakePHP](http://api.cakephp.org/class/router) [Symfony2](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/routing.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is a `router` (if I didn't misunderstood your question).

Checkout for example how the [Zend Framework](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.router.html) does it.

It would be pretty simple to implement a router yourself.

Comment: Exactly how easy would this be? Do you mean using Zend or writing my own? Do you have any examples. Thanks!

Comment: I've written one myself (for my own custom framework) and it didn't take long (less then a day). Just look at how the other frameworks are doing it to get an idea.